# An equation satisfied by harmonic coordinates in a Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, scattering, research-level, linearized-theory

(Full disclosure, this is very much a "fish out of water" type situation: I'm working on something in an area very far away from the stuff I usually work with, so this is hopefully something basic/simple, I'm just not seeing it due to a lack of experience.)

I've been reading through the paper [Eikonal amplitudes from curved backgrounds](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.09113) in which a correspondence between $2 \to 2$ scattering in a flat background and $1 \to 1$ scattering in a curved background (in the Eikonal limit where $−t\ll s$) is established. There's one specific spot in the paper in which I'm a bit lost:

> Given that the eikonal phase is gauge invariant, we can choose any coordinate system for the metric tensor. Picking for example harmonic coordiantes for Schwarzschild, its linearized form is
> $$h^{\mu\nu}(x)=\mathcal{P}^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\bigg(u_\alpha u_\beta\frac{4MG}{r}\bigg), \tag{5.6} $$
> where we have introduced the projector $\mathcal{P}^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}=\tfrac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\alpha}\eta^{\nu\beta}+\tfrac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\beta}\eta^{\nu\alpha}-\tfrac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta^{\alpha\beta}$ and $Mu_\alpha=P_\alpha$.

Here $h^{\mu\nu}$ is the usual inverse of the perturbation of the Schwarzschild metric away from flat space $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$ and the paper says earlier (below equation (1.1)) that $P_\alpha$ is the 4-momentum of the background source.

**Question:** *Where does this equation come from? In particular, I don't really see how the $u_\alpha$ and $u_\beta$ appear.*

I am somewhat familiar with the harmonic coordinates in which the metric (with $c$ set to 1) is
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=-\frac{\rho-MG}{\rho+MG}\mathrm{d}t^2+\frac{\rho+MG}{\rho-MG}\mathrm{d}\rho^2+(\rho+MG)^2(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin^2\theta \mathrm{d}\varphi^2),$$
and at a very naive level can see something of this form arising from the form of the harmonic gauge condition $ \ 0=g^{\mu\nu}\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}$, as this gives you $h^{\mu\nu}\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}$, so the left side at least contains $h^{\mu\nu}$ and the right side certainly looks very reminiscent of the projector $\mathcal{P}^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ in form. But... yeah, I'm not sure how exactly to derive (5.6) in detail, nor what the 4-velocity $u$'s have to do with it. Any help clarifying this would be greatly appreciated.

(Or, at the very least, can someone help me with interpreting the $u_\alpha$’s themselves? What are the the 4-velocity of? It seems as if this relation is simply a fact about the harmonic coordinates themselves, ie of the background spacetime itself as opposed to some particles moving through it, and the schwarzschild spacetime is static, so I’m not sure what they actually capture…)